# Changing value of input's model programmatically using angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic framework to create my app.

I have a text input, with `ng-model="answer"`, and bellow a have a button that starts speech recognition and then replaces the input text with the spoken one.

The problem is that I can't change the input's text programmatically when using the mic with `$scope.answer="any text"`, it looks like it just doesn't change the view's value.

I found that I have to use a directive in order to bind the model, but to be honest I don't know how to address it right now.
Also I've tried `$scope.$apply()` but it works only the first time and when I haven't wrote any test directly to the input yet.

Comment: Can you include the code that changes the `$scope.answer` programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for may be Angulars `$watch()` function, so you can handle any model changes even outside of the input field.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch